# retrieve google ads version programically

Tags: android, admob, google-ads-api

I'm using the latest google ads sdk version admob (via gradle)

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
```

and I'm trying to retrieve the version programically. In IOS the version is retrieved via [GADRequest sdkVersion] but I couldn't find how to retrieve it in android